# Return row of 2D array as comma delimited string given row number Java

Tags: java, string, function, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to create a function that will accept the row number of a multi-dimensional array as an integer and return a string that contains a comma-delimited list of the values in that row.

`this.desks` is the 2d array containing string values. `this.oneRow` is a string that I would like the function to return.

`sb` is a stringbuilder. Row is the value of the row that should be returned. This block of code is what I've managed to find but it returns the entire array. I've attempted to look at the syntax for string builder and modify it to no avail. Would someone mind assisting?

```
public String getRow(int row) {

    for(String[] s1 : this.desks) {
        this.sb.append(Arrays.toString(s1));
        this.oneRow = sb.toString();
       }
     return this.oneRow;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be looping if you want the first row, use index `row` (after first checking it's a valid index). Like,

```
public String getRow(int row) {
    if (row < desks.length) {
        return Arrays.toString(desks[row]);
    }
    return ""; // <-- or null, or throw an exception.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.oneRow += sb.toString();
```

the values to be concatenated.